# Print and connect Jack Audio and MIDI ports from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, jack, midi

How do I print and connect jack-audio and midi ports from the command line, similar to `aconnect -io` or `aconnect 20:0 132:1` for inputs and outputs of ALSA MIDI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**jack_lsp** [options] [filter string]

is able to print all jack ports (Audio and MIDI).

---

**From the help-text:**

List active Jack ports, and optionally display extra information.
Optionally filter ports which match ALL strings provided after any options.

```
Display options:
        -s, --server <name>   Connect to the jack server named <name>
        -A, --aliases         List aliases for each port
        -c, --connections     List connections to/from each port
        -l, --latency         Display per-port latency in frames at each port
        -L, --latency         Display total latency in frames at each port
        -p, --properties      Display port properties. Output may include:
                              input|output, can-monitor, physical, terminal

        -t, --type            Display port type
        -h, --help            Display this help message
        --version             Output version information and exit
```

For more information see http://jackaudio.org/

---

to connect the ports from the command line, you can use `jack_connect`.

with `jack_lsp` you could get an output like this showing all current jack ports:

```
system:capture_1
system:capture_2
system:playback_1
system:playback_2
system:midi_capture_1
system:midi_playback_1
amsynth:L out
amsynth:R out
amsynth:midi_in
system:midi_playback_2
system:midi_capture_2
```

as an example you could connect `system:midi_capture_1` with `amsynth:midi_in` by running: `jack_connect system:midi_capture_1 amsynth:midi_in`

To see which ports are connected you could use `jack_lsp -c` and get an output similar to this:

```
system:capture_1
system:capture_2
system:playback_1
   amsynth:L out
system:playback_2
   amsynth:R out
system:midi_capture_1
   amsynth:midi_in
system:midi_playback_1
amsynth:L out
   system:playback_1
amsynth:R out
   system:playback_2
amsynth:midi_in
   system:midi_capture_1
system:midi_playback_2
system:midi_capture_2
```